# Setting a checkbox's drawable in xml

Tags: android, xml, checkbox, drawable

How do I set a checkbox's drawable in XML? In code I'm using

```
fbox.setButtonDrawable();
```

But I don't see an XML attribute that does the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

android:button="@drawable/..."

Should be a statelistdrawable

Comment: Well, that was obvious =\ I didn't think button would be the drawable for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

it's an attribute derived from `CompoundButton`: see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#CompoundButton).